# Prove $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}<\arctan\left(x\right)$ for every $x>0$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Prove $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}<\arctan\left(x\right)$ for every $x>0$

I thought about MVT , what i did is :

let $g(x) = \arctan\left(x\right) $

so by MVT there is $c\in (0,x)$ such that :

$g'(c) = \frac{g\left(x\right)-g\left(0\right)}{x-0} \implies \frac{1}{c^2+1} = \frac{\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}$

now i need to prove that $\frac{x}{c^2+1}>\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

any hint how to prove this  ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)= \arctan x - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Evaluate

$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}>0$$

So, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$. Thus, $f(x) > f(0) = 0$, or

$$\arctan x > \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing derivatives and integrating the difference from 0 to $x$.

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$$